# How to fix Getting unknown property in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I installed web apps for Library Management, when i login and go to account profile it give me error like this (*Edited for more detail code*)

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
> Getting unknown property: common\models\Members::Array

This is my stack trace:

```
1. in /otka/app/src/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php at line 146
foreach ($this->_behaviors as $behavior) {
                if ($behavior->canGetProperty($name)) {
                    return $behavior->$name;
                }
            }
        }
        if (method_exists($this, 'set' . $name)) {
            throw new InvalidCallException('Getting write-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
        } else {
            throw new UnknownPropertyException('Getting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name); #this is line 146
        }
    }
2. in /otka/app/src/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php at line 247– yii\base\Component::__get('Array')
3. in /otka/app/src/web/keanggotaan/views/user/index.php at line 101– yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::__get('Array')
4. in /otka/app/src/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php at line 325– require('/otka/app/src/web/keanggotaan/vi...')
5. in /otka/app/src/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php at line 247– yii\base\View::renderPhpFile('/otka/app/src/web/keanggotaan/vi...', ['model' => common\models\Members, 'membersInfoForm' => [['ID' => '54', 'Member_Field_id' => '1', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:20', ...], ['ID' => '55', 'Member_Field_id' => '2', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ['ID' => '56', 'Member_Field_id' => '5', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ['ID' => '57', 'Member_Field_id' => '6', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ...]])
6. in /otka/app/src/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php at line 149– yii\base\View::renderFile('/otka/app/src/web/keanggotaan/vi...', ['model' => common\models\Members, 'membersInfoForm' => [['ID' => '54', 'Member_Field_id' => '1', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:20', ...], ['ID' => '55', 'Member_Field_id' => '2', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ['ID' => '56', 'Member_Field_id' => '5', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ['ID' => '57', 'Member_Field_id' => '6', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ...]], keanggotaan\controllers\UserController)
7. in /otka/app/src/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php at line 377– yii\base\View::render('index', ['model' => common\models\Members, 'membersInfoForm' => [['ID' => '54', 'Member_Field_id' => '1', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:20', ...], ['ID' => '55', 'Member_Field_id' => '2', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ['ID' => '56', 'Member_Field_id' => '5', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ['ID' => '57', 'Member_Field_id' => '6', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ...]], keanggotaan\controllers\UserController)
8. in /otka/app/src/web/keanggotaan/controllers/UserController.php at line 69– yii\base\Controller::render('index', ['model' => common\models\Members, 'membersInfoForm' => [['ID' => '54', 'Member_Field_id' => '1', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:20', ...], ['ID' => '55', 'Member_Field_id' => '2', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ['ID' => '56', 'Member_Field_id' => '5', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ['ID' => '57', 'Member_Field_id' => '6', 'CreateBy' => null, 'CreateDate' => '2016-03-07 11:26:21', ...], ...]])
9. keanggotaan\controllers\UserController::actionIndex()
10. in /otka/app/src/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php at line 55– call_user_func_array([keanggotaan\controllers\UserController, 'actionIndex'], [])
11. in /otka/app/src/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php at line 154– yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams([])
12. in /otka/app/src/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php at line 454– yii\base\Controller::runAction('index', [])
13. in /otka/app/src/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php at line 84– yii\base\Module::runAction('user/index', [])
14. in /otka/app/src/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php at line 375– yii\web\Application::handleRequest(yii\web\Request)
15. in /otka/app/src/web/keanggotaan/index.php at line 18– yii\base\Application::run()
```

This is the function line in Component.php

```
public function __get($name)
{
    $getter = 'get' . $name;
    if (method_exists($this, $getter)) {
        // read property, e.g. getName()
        return $this->$getter();
    } else {
        // behavior property
        $this->ensureBehaviors();
        foreach ($this->_behaviors as $behavior) {
            if ($behavior->canGetProperty($name)) {
                return $behavior->$name;
            }
        }
    }
    if (method_exists($this, 'set' . $name)) {
        throw new InvalidCallException('Getting write-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
    } else {
        throw new UnknownPropertyException('Getting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
    }
}
```

This is my keanggotaan\controllers\UserControllers.php

```
<?php

namespace keanggotaan\controllers;

use common\models\Members;
use common\models\MembersInfoForm;
use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

use yii\helpers\Url;


/**
 * Description of UserController
 *
 * @author Henry <alvin_vna@yahoo.com>
 */
class UserController extends Controller{
    
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
            'page' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',
            ],
        ];
    }
    
   /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex(){
         if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {

             //Get Custom Field Form.
             $membersInfoForm = MembersInfoForm::find()
                 ->where(['Jenis_Perpustakaan_id' => Yii::$app->config->get('JenisPerpustakaan')])
                 ->asArray()->all();

      /*      echo "<pre>";
            print_r($membersInfoForm);
            die;
*/
            $model = $this->findModel(\Yii::$app->user->identity->NoAnggota);
            return $this->render('index',['model'=>$model,'membersInfoForm'=>$membersInfoForm]);
        }else{
            return $this->redirect(['site/login']);
        }
    }
    
    public function actionChangePassword()
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['__id'];

        $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;
        $loadedPost = $user->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

        if ($loadedPost && $user->validate()) {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand('UPDATE membersonline SET membersonline.Password="'.sha1($user->newPassword).'", membersonline.UpdateDate=NOW() WHERE membersonline.ID="'.Yii::$app->user->identity->id.'"')->execute();
            // $user->Password = sha1($user->newPassword);
            // $user->save(false);

            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', [
                'type' => 'info',
                'duration' => 500,
                'icon' => 'fa fa-info-circle',
                'message' => Yii::t('app', 'Password berhasil dirubah.'),
                'title' => 'Info',
                'positonY' => Yii::$app->params['flashMessagePositionY'],
                'positonX' => Yii::$app->params['flashMessagePositionX']
            ]);
            return $this->refresh();
        } 

        return $this->render('change-password', [
            'user' => $user,
            ]);

    }

    protected function findModel($nomorAnggota)
    {
        if (($model = Members::find()->where(['MemberNo'=>$nomorAnggota])->one()) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

And this is my index.php at keanggotaan

```
            if($membersInfoForm[$i]['Member_Field_id'] == 13){
               if($model->$data[$i]){
                    $identitas = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT Nama FROM master_jenis_identitas WHERE id = ".$model->$data[$i]."")->queryOne();
                    echo "<td>".$identitas['Nama']."</td>"; 
               }else{
                    echo "<td>-</td>";
               }

            }else if($membersInfoForm[$i]['Member_Field_id'] == 15){
                if($model->$data[$i]){
                    $jenis_kelamin = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT Name FROM jenis_kelamin WHERE ID = ".$model->$data[$i]."")->queryOne();
                    echo "<td>".$jenis_kelamin['Name']."</td>"; 
                }else{
                    echo "<td>-</td>";
                }

            }else if($membersInfoForm[$i]['Member_Field_id'] == 16){
                if($model->$data[$i]){
                    $pekerjaan = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT Pekerjaan FROM master_pekerjaan WHERE id = ".$model->$data[$i]."")->queryOne();
                    echo "<td>".$pekerjaan['Pekerjaan']."</td>"; 
                }else{
                    echo "<td>-</td>";
                }

            }else if($membersInfoForm[$i]['Member_Field_id'] == 17){
                if($model->$data[$i]){
                    $agama = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT Name FROM agama WHERE ID = ".$model->$data[$i]."")->queryOne();
                    echo "<td>".$agama['Name']."</td>"; 
                }else{
                    echo "<td>-</td>";
                }

            }else if($membersInfoForm[$i]['Member_Field_id'] == 18){
                if($model->$data[$i]){
                    $jenisanggota = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT jenisanggota FROM jenis_anggota WHERE id = ".$model->$data[$i]."")->queryOne();
                    echo "<td>".$jenisanggota['jenisanggota']."</td>"; 
                }else{
                    echo "<td>-</td>";
                }
                
            }else if($membersInfoForm[$i]['Member_Field_id'] == 19){
                if($model->$data[$i]){
                    $pendidikan = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT Nama FROM master_pendidikan WHERE id = ".$model->$data[$i]."")->queryOne();
                    echo "<td>".$pendidikan['Nama']."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>-</td>";
                }
                
            }else{
                if($model->$data[$i]){
                    echo "<td>".$model->$data[$i]."</td>"; #this is line 101
                }else{
                    echo "<td>-</td>";
                }
                
            }
```

And this is my yii\db\BaseActiveRecord.php at function __get('Array')

```
public function __get($name)
{
    if (isset($this->_attributes[$name]) || array_key_exists($name, $this->_attributes)) {
        return $this->_attributes[$name];
    } elseif ($this->hasAttribute($name)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        if (isset($this->_related[$name]) || array_key_exists($name, $this->_related)) {
            return $this->_related[$name];
        }
        $value = parent::__get($name);
        if ($value instanceof ActiveQueryInterface) {
            return $this->_related[$name] = $value->findFor($name, $this);
        } else {
            return $value;
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: *"I installed web apps for Library Management"*, if you installed an extension then please also provide the link to it. The code shown is from a core class. I would recommend you not to change there anything. Can you provide the coding of the `actionIndex`-method in `keanggotaan\controllers\UserController`?

Comment: The error might also come from `/otka/app/src/web/keanggotaan/views/user/index.php at line 101– yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::__get('Array')`, probably best you also show some code around the the line 101.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal Ok, I edited my question for more detail. I not change anything except some 'word' because I'm using php 7.4

Comment: Which line is 101? (`/otka/app/src/web/keanggotaan/views/user/index.php at line 101`)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal the last else I write #this is line 101

Comment: What are you intending to do there: `$model->$data[$i]`? This currently is interpreted as `($model->$data)[$i]` is this what you want? Or should `$data[$i]` be evaluates first and then the value should be used on the model? You would do it like this then: `$model->{$data[$i]}`. If that doesnt answer your question: Provide for each variable the value in `$model->$data[$i]`.